# Iterate through array

Tags: php, arrays

I am having hard time with this array output as I am dont know how to get ID value form the output. I can get other values but for ID I get null whe I dump it.

here is array output:

```
array(3) { 
[0]=> array(4) { 
    ["acf_fc_layout"]=> string(15) "options" 
    ["payments"]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> object(WP_Post)#10502 (24) { 
            ["ID"]=> int(7190) 
            ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" 
            ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2021-09-10 14:49:54" 
            ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" 
            ["post_content"]=> string(4) "TEST" 
            ["post_title"]=> string(4) "TEST" 
            ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["post_status"]=> string(5) "draft" 
            ["comment_status"]=> string(6) "closed" 
            ["ping_status"]=> string(6) "closed" 
            ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["post_name"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["pinged"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2021-09-10 14:49:54" 
            ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2021-09-10 12:49:54" 
            ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["post_parent"]=> int(0) 
            ["guid"]=> string(73) "https://url.com" 
            ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_type"]=> string(7) "payment" 
            ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0" 
            ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" 
        } 
    } 
    ["link"]=> bool(false) 
    ["home"]=> bool(true) 
}
```

Then I do for each loop through the array loop. I can get variables link and home but id var shows NULL.

```
foreach($payments as $a){
   $link = $a["link"];
   $home= $a["home"];
   $id = $["payments"]["ID"];
}
```

I am not sure what is wrong here, I am new at programming and this array seems to be a bit complicated for me. I was googling but cannot find a similar example.

Comment: It should be `$a["payments"][0]["ID"]` ...

Comment: @arkascha When I do that I get this error Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type WP_Post as array in.

Comment: The elements are `WP_Post` objects, not arrays. So `$a["payments"][0]->ID`

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong key to access the `ID` field.

As @Barmer commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69146877/iterate-through-array#comment122211915_69146877) the element `0` in your `$payments` array is an `WP_Post` object. So you have to access the `ID` with this call:

```php
$a["payments"][0]->ID
```